# ArcGIS Online shows data error

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer

I have about 7000 records in a feature layer. It was all fine but when I updated the features of record, suddenly on ArcGIS Online when I open the "Data" tab first it shows data loading (7000 records) and suddenly after that it shows "data error" and I don't see any previous data.

What can I do?

Comment: do you have a backup of your data?

Comment: no, I dont have the latest backup

Comment: @Mapperz I realize yes I do have a backup. but is there not any option to do it without backup

Comment: Sounds like data corruption to me. You'd have to review the source with other tools to get an idea of the scope of the failure.

Comment: What part of the ArcGIS platform are you referring to as the “ArcGIS web”?

Comment: I have my data at https://developers.arcgis.com/layers/?id=123213213something

Comment: I *think* that means you are using a Developer license to access ArcGIS Online so I’ll edit your tags accordingly.